# Instances growing along and with the growth on the curve?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, procedural

I am hoping to achieve an effect that looks like thorns growing from vines. I am able to trim the vines and animate them growing, however I would like to add 'thorns' that grow from the trunk along with the growth of the vines.

Currently I have the vines:

[image]

Here is my node set up:

[image]

I have tried capturing the spline parameter factor and using it as an input in scale instances. But even with a float curve, math nodes or color mix nodes I can't quite get the effect I'm going for. Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: I did something like that (growing veins with branch, sub-branch, ...) using a *Simulation Zone*. Basically, at each frame extruding all branches end, using *Attributes* to keep track of deepness of branches, extrusion speed, stop extruding, etc ... I'll try simplify it and write an answer. *Simulation Zones* are really powerful but harder to grasp.

Answer (score 3):

If this is the effect you're trying to make, here is how it can be done :

[image]

Here, I instanced cones along the base curve which I converted to points to get the rotation value that I used to correctly align the cones

In order to get the scaling effect, make sure to capture the factor after you trim the curve. You can then reverse the factor with a map range node, so that the tip instances are shorter than the base ones

[image]

Hope that helps